# How to call an action method from JSP and pass a parameter in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts

I have the following code in JSP that would call an action method and then pass a parameter value.

```xml
<s:param name="lastname" value="outputData.Lastname"></s:param>
<li> Your fullname is: <s:property name = "fullname" value="%{getFullname(lastname)}"/> </li>
```

This is how it looks like in the action method:

```java
public String getFullname (String lastname) throws Exception {
     String firstname = someClass.getFirstname();
     return firstname + lastname;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I  use the param name to pass the value, the passed value is `null`. But when I do it like the code below, it successfully passes the value.

```xml
<li> Your fullname is: <s:property name = "fullname" value="%{getFullname('Doe')}"/> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`<s:param>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/param-tag.html) tag doesn't work for setting a value to the variable. You should use [`<s:set>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/set-tag.html) tag. It will create a variable in the `action` scope which is used by default.

> The value will be set in the page scope and Struts’ action context using the name as key

```xml
<s:set var="lastname">Doe</s:set>
<li> Your fullname is: <s:property name = "fullname" value="%{getFullname(lastname)}"/> </li>
```